# Recovering data from external HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have the main hdd of another laptop which was damaged (the laptop) on which there are some pictures and video I would like to recover. The HDD of the damaged laptop had Ubuntu on it.

How can I access the files in this drive? I tried to connect the HDD with Sata usb cable but it is not mounting for whatever reason.

Thank you all

Comment: You've provided no specific details.  Have you checked the health of the drive?  did it get data back (electronics are working thus they aren't the issue with the drive, as SMART doesn't touch the media getting data from the electronics on the drive itself).  When you connected it, how was it shown to various queries (`lsblk` to list block devices, `blkid` to list block devices IDs etc..). If you attempted to mount it, what command did you use? and what error resulted? (if not a terminal command, or you use GUI what appeared in the system logs on the attempt to `mount`; ie. `dmesg` etc)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: You should also let us know what OS is on the device you're currently using - the device to which you hooked up the now-external drive.

Comment: @guiverc fair comment  -please let me give you some more data. I am pretty sure that the HDD is not physically damaged.   lsblk returns this:                                                                  
frosty@frosty-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ lsblk
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 465,8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 596,2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 596,2G  0 part

Comment: @guiver  blkid returns: my disk and this/dev/sdb1: UUID="VKGiZQ-9CfN-s8Ho-2xo2-GGcN-9ScK-f2c7kE" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="77e57383-01"

Comment: @KGill - I am using ubuntu and the damaged machine was also using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You still can mount it manually. Use the command line!

Check the available disks and partitions:

```
sudo lsblk
```

You have to see all your disks there and all the partitions on the disks. The last column `MOUNTPOINT` will be empty for the partition you are interested in (otherwise it's already mounted and you can reach the files).
No you can mount that partition (sdb3 in my example):

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/
```

Now you can reach all your files in the /mnt directory.

At this point you may face an issue. If your [UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) and your UID on the other system is not the same you can have permission issues. Of course as `root` you can reach every file.

Comment: after mounting I would make a diskdump (`dd` ) and extract the files from that disk dump and not the actual disk,

Comment: @redseven - When I try to mount I get this back:                                                             frosty@frosty-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.

Comment: Looks like you had LVM on your old PC. Mount the LVM volume instead of the partition. `lsblk` also shows you what volumes you have on that partition. Copy&paste the output of `lsblk` here if you can't solve it on your own.

Comment: @Rinzwind: if the old disk is physically in good condition I don't see a good reason for the dump (dd). If you worry to change something unintentionally on the old disk just use read only mount.

Comment: When it comes to restoring ... safety comes 1st.